# Какой протокол гарантирует передачу файла без ошибок?

Tags: ftp, tcp-ip, protocol, сеть, ssh

**Задача**: передать файл с одного компа на другой по сети.

**Вопрос**: насколько я понимаю, при передаче файл может стать corrupted. Это так? Если да, то какой протокол гарантирует, что он не будет corrupted?

Дают ли такие гарантии TCP, FTP, SSH, HTTP?

Comment: @sp7, все верно, то есть получается что проверки md5 и checksum не заложены ни в один протокол передачи файлов и я всегда должен писать их сам? это мне кажется странным. но тем не менее, хочу зафиксировать - это действительно так?

Comment: SSH: "Целостность передачи данных проверяется с помощью CRC32 в SSH1 или HMAC-SHA1/HMAC-MD5 в SSH2"

Comment: @KutaBeach 

> то есть получается что проверки md5 и checksum не заложены ни в один протокол передачи файлов и я всегда должен писать их сам.

Здесь я вам ответа не дам, так как никогда не задавался целью выяснить это. Возможно сейчас уже существуют какие-нибудь классы-обертки в которых это реализовано, но на счет стандартных возможностей не знаю. В принципе предложенный мной вариант не сложен для реализации. Поэтому скорее всего вы быстрее его напишите, чем будите выяснять все возможности протоколов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где и когда Вы видели в принципе 100% гарантию чего либо. Протоколы в данном случае не исключение. Слишком много разных моментов возникает при передачи файлов.

P.S. Единственное, что приходит на ум, чтобы хоть как-то узнать насколько корректно был передан файл - это проверять MD5 переданного файла.

Comment: @sp7, вы же знаете про crc в tcp?

Comment: CRC в TCP не очень надежная защита от ошибок передачи. 

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, какой процент вероятности отказа?

Comment: @Etki, что вы понимаете под вероятностью отказа?

Comment: @sp7, вероятность нахождения битого пакета, в котором сойдется crc.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830206/can-a-tcp-checksum-produce-a-false-positive-if-yes-how-is-this-dealt-with)  обсуждение темы непойманных ошибок в CRC с разными ссылками.

    The TCP checksum alone has a probability of 1 in 65536 errors not being detected.

Comment: То есть ошибки при передаче возможны даже при использовании reliable протокола TCP. Следовательно, инженеры как-то с этим работают. Как? SSH надежнее? Или FTP? Лучше проверять checksum или md5? Эта проверка встроена в какой-нибудь протокол? Я же не первый, кто задался этим вопросом..

Comment: @KutaBeach, во-первых явно не стоит наугад тыкать в протоколы. Без википедии конечо не скажу, но мне сдается, что и SSH, и HTTP, и FTP базируются на TCP. Во-вторых будет очень сложно добиться гарантий передачи точной копии файла, пока следом за самим файлом не приходит точная его копия. Ну и в-третьих непонятно, как именно вы это собрались применять - вам на собственный сервер файлы закидывать (т.е. сгодится и консоль) или встраивать это в приложение.
В принципе, метод действительно только вышеописанный - передавать контрольные суммы (можно несколько, можно попакетно) и проверять их на клиент

Comment: @KutaBeach, насколько помню, FTP не использует дополнительных проверок. 

Поскольку SSH занимается шифрованием (и возможно, компрессией), то видимо вероятность передачи искаженных данных по нему ниже.

Про самостоятельную проверку (MD5) Вам уже написали.

Comment: @avp
А CRC 32-bit соответственно 1 к 2^32

Comment: @KutaBeach  > Как? SSH надежнее? Или FTP? Лучше проверять checksum или md5?

Делайте так, как Вам самому проще или легче реализовать.  Я бы копал в сторону md5. Пример реализации в лоб, мог бы выглядеть следующим образом. 1) Отправляете файл на сервер 2) По окончании загрузки сравниваете md5 файла на компьютере и сервере. 3) Если все сходится, делаете вывод что выгрузка прошла успешно. P.S. Я думаю, что в вашем случае нет необходимости учитывать такие ситуации что исходящий трафик может быть перехвачен, изменен и т.п. Поэтому такое и не рассматриваем.

Comment: @smackmychi, в самом деле 32 бит?

А я всегда думал, что `unsigned short` это 16 бит....

(впрочем, [я не один такой](http://locklessinc.com/articles/tcp_checksum/)).

--

А вот в Ethernet пакетах (data link layer) в самом деле используют 32-бит crc ([подробнее тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_check_sequence)).

Только ведь речь шла именно об ошибках TCP, т.е. оставшихся ошибках, которые не были отловлены более низкими уровнями в передаче данных.

Comment: И что дальше? У вас паранойя или я действительно говорил про TCP 32-bit CRC?

Comment: Получается, что такая простейшая проверка на правильность отправки файла нигде не реализована? Это странно.

Comment: А про что вы говорили

      @avp А CRC 32-bit соответственно 1 к 2^32

в своем комментарии ???

--

Интересно, если учесть оба CRC получим 1 к 2^48?

Кстати, учитывая [Typical Error Rate](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=683070) в media  от 10E-5 до 10E-13 (оптика) получим ничтожную вероятность передачи сбойного файла по TCP (FTP)

(хотя, говорят, что прецеденты имели место...).

Comment: Я не ищу 100% божественной надежности. Я просто хочу понять, как люди решают простейшую проблему, с которой мы все сталкиваемся каждый день. Очевидно, над этим уже подумали.
____
Мне несложно передать, допустим, md5 файла и потом сравнить с результатом. Просто я хотел понять, надо ли это делать, может быть, это уже есть в самой реализации протокола. Я же ведь не проверяю, не поменялись ли местами биты в файле, хотя пакеты могут прийти в разном порядке.

Comment: @KutaBeach
> Я просто хочу понять, как люди решают простейшую проблему, с которой мы все сталкиваемся каждый день
Приведу вам простой пример. Например, когда вы выгружаете файл на файлообменник или облако, то как там решается ситуация, что файл был выгружен корректно? Да, по сути, никак. При этом вы даже можете получить сообщение от файлообменника, что все было выгружено ОК. А когда начнете скачивать файл обратно, то обнаружите, что все не так и гладко. Сколько раз я, и думаю вы сталкивались с ситуацией, когда скачиваете, какой-нибудь архив и не можете его распаковать из-за того, что он битый

Comment: @KutaBeach, когда я писал про 

>когда начнете скачивать файл обратно, то обнаружите, что все не так и гладко. Сколько раз я и, думаю, вы сталкивались с ситуацией, когда скачиваете какой-нибудь архив и не можете его распаковать из-за того, что он битый. 

то имел ввиду, что файл изначально был выгружен некорректно. Т.е. тот вариант, что у вас возникли ошибки при скачивании, мы сейчас не рассматриваем. P.S. Кроме того, вы, может быть, заметили, что часто с выложенным для загрузки файлом указывают его md5, чтобы пользователи, его скачавшие, могли потом сравнить с тем, что у них.

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) вроде бы всегда проверяет целостность переданных файлов.